# Parsing JSON using Python and if statement

Tags: python, json

Here is the JSON data I have:

```
{
  "response": {
    "status": {
      "version": "4.2",
      "code": 0,
      "message": "Success"
    },
    "artists": [
      {
        "name": "Taylor Swift",
        "foreign_ids": [
          {
            "catalog": "facebook",
            "foreign_id": "facebook:artist:19614945368"
          }
        ],
        "hotttnesss": 0.99956,
        "id": "ARS54I31187FB46721"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ed Sheeran",
        "foreign_ids": [
          {
            "catalog": "facebook",
            "foreign_id": "facebook:artist:9189674485"
          }
        ],
        "hotttnesss": 0.994265,
        "id": "ARSDWSZ122ECCB706A"
      },
      {
        "name": "Calvin Harris",
        "foreign_ids": [
          {
            "catalog": "facebook",
            "foreign_id": "facebook:artist:19366141168"
          }
        ],
        "hotttnesss": 0.990559,
        "id": "ARJRB241187FB556A3"
      },
      {
        "name": "Sam Smith",
        "foreign_ids": [
          {
            "catalog": "facebook",
            "foreign_id": "facebook:artist:313595788739120"
          }
        ],
        "hotttnesss": 0.988203,
        "id": "ARUZM8A11C8A41519C"
      },
      {
        "name": "Maroon 5",
        "foreign_ids": [
          {
            "catalog": "facebook",
            "foreign_id": "facebook:artist:5330548481"
          }
        ],
        "hotttnesss": 0.984929,
        "id": "ARF5M7Q1187FB501E8"
      },
      {
        "name": "Sia",
        "foreign_ids": [
          {
            "catalog": "facebook",
            "foreign_id": "facebook:artist:10959868407"
          }
        ],
        "hotttnesss": 0.983516,
        "id": "AR6ENUY1187B994158"
      },
      {
        "name": "David Guetta",
        "foreign_ids": [
          {
            "catalog": "facebook",
            "foreign_id": "facebook:artist:7619396355"
          }
        ],
        "hotttnesss": 0.982656,
        "id": "ARH2QI91187FB3788D"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ellie Goulding",
        "foreign_ids": [
          {
            "catalog": "facebook",
            "foreign_id": "facebook:artist:135027136641"
          }
        ],
        "hotttnesss": 0.981786,
        "id": "ARKTTJV12592CDA07F"
      },
      {
        "name": "Wiz Khalifa",
        "foreign_ids": [
          {
            "catalog": "facebook",
            "foreign_id": "facebook:artist:12138756141"
          }
        ],
        "hotttnesss": 0.978492,
        "id": "ARN0GFV1187FB508CC"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ariana Grande",
        "hotttnesss": 0.978074,
        "id": "AROHQCR13244CF7152"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm trying to parse "catalog" and "foreign_id".  Here is my code:

```
for item in data['response']['artists']:
    for row in item['foreign_ids']:
        print row['catalog'], row['foreign_id']
```

The results are:

```
facebook facebook:artist:19614945368
facebook facebook:artist:9189674485
facebook facebook:artist:19366141168
facebook facebook:artist:313595788739120
facebook facebook:artist:5330548481
facebook facebook:artist:10959868407
facebook facebook:artist:7619396355
facebook facebook:artist:135027136641
facebook facebook:artist:12138756141

KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-224-cbc34d6d831e> in <module>()
      1 for item in data['response']['artists']:
----> 2     for row in item['foreign_ids']:
      3         print row['catalog'], row['foreign_id']

KeyError: 'foreign_ids'
```

I think I know why; the last data row does not have "foreign_ids". How would I include an if statement to help me avoid this error? For example, the code outputs "None" when there is no array value called "foreign_ids".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check to see if that column exists before you attempt to iterate over it.  This approach is known as "look before you leap".  Here we're using `get`, since it will return `None` by default and not raise the `KeyError`.

```
for item in data['response']['artists']:
    if item.get('foreign_ids'):
        for row in item['foreign_ids']:
            print row['catalog'], row['foreign_id']
```

Alternatively, you could employ a default value through `get` which supplies an empty list to iterate over instead.

```
for item in data['response']['artists']:
    for row in item.get('foreign_ids', []):
        print row['catalog'], row['foreign_id']
```

In both cases, **you have to check to see if that key exists**.  The code you have assumes that it's always present, which is definitely not the case.

Comment: Thank you all for the nice suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You could check to see if the key is in that part of the JSON object by doing:

```
if 'somekey' in somPartOfTheJson:
    jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)

    for item in jsonObj['response']['artists']:
        if 'foreign_ids' in item:
            for row in item['foreign_ids']:
                if 'catalog' in row and 'foreign_id' in row:
                    print row['catalog'], row['foreign_id']
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an `if` statement (which is perfectly valid), you can use a try/except block:

```
for item in data['response']['artists']:
    try:    
        for row in item['foreign_ids']:
            print row['catalog'], row['foreign_id']
    except KeyError as Ex:
        print "{} not found in {}".format(Ex,item)
```

This gives:

```
...
facebook facebook:artist:7619396355
facebook facebook:artist:135027136641
facebook facebook:artist:12138756141
'foreign_ids' not found in {'id': 'AROHQCR13244CF7152', 'name': 'Ariana Grande', 'hotttnesss': 0.978074}
```

which IMO is cleaner since it explicitly acknowledges the problem and acts on it. Instead of print, you can do an alternate action like a [log](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
if 'foreign_ids' not in item:
    continue
for row in item['foreign_ids']:
....
```

Comment: I'd have written it the other way (as in, `if 'foreign_ids' in item:`), but this suffices.

Comment: I prefer the continue method as it alleviates using lots of indentation :). To each their own.